# Deploying WAR on Tomcat via Docker - 404

Tags: docker, http-status-code-404, tomcat8

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:10-jdk8
MAINTAINER your_name
# COPY path-to-your-application-war path-to-webapps-in-docker-tomcat
COPY demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

The WAR is a Springboot application with just this controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", name);
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I've built the image and ran the container. However, when I hit http://localhost:8080/hello, I get a 404. The logs inside the container say that the application has been deployed:

```
10-May-2021 08:57:13.253 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
10-May-2021 08:57:14.882 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
10-May-2021 08:57:15.043 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [1,790] ms
```

Why am I getting the HTTP 404?

Edit: The command I used to run the container is:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 0ae485a6f486
```

I've followed these instructions to create a deployable WAR https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file
albeit with no success.

My demo project can be found here: https://github.com/th3r10n/spring-boot-war

I built it as:

```
./mvnw package
```

Comment: I think the WAR will be deployed within the tomcat and so the URL to get to the hello servlet will be http://localhost:8080/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/hello by default. You would need to adjust the deployment options (name of the WAR, what path to deploy to, etc.) if you wish to have a different path.

Comment: Can you add your "docker run" command, or your "docker-compose", in order we can help

Comment: hi @Marvin, the command I used is docker run -p 8080:8080 0ae485a6f486

Comment: hi @JohnFergus, the result is the same i.e. a 404, just with a different message: The requested resource [/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/hello] is not available

Comment: Without access to your application (and how you built it) I cannot diagnose the problem. There could be many issues causing the problem - a quick google throws up lots of similar questions with various things to try. It could be how you built the WAR, what Spring options it has, etc.

Comment: @JohnFergus, I've added the repository with my code.

Answer (score 1):

I took your app, built the WAR and deployed to a local tomcat. If I hit the `/hello` servlet (or indeed the root `/` servlet) I get a 404 error and I can see errors in the server stdout telling me that the code is missing configuration/setup that would make it work -

[image]

In the logs I see ...

`ERROR 24336 --- [102-8002-exec-6] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine  : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-172.20.248.102-8002-exec-6] Exception processing template "hello": Error resolving template [hello], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

... So this is an issue with your application - it basically is incomplete and does not work. You should get it working locally (as a stand-alone spring boot app, within a tomcat locally or whatever you want) before worrying about trying to deploy it to Docker. Once you have proved your WAR is working locally then you should have no problem deploying it within Docker the way you deployed it now.

Answer (score 0):

## Expose 8080 in Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:jdk8-corretto
MAINTAINER your_name
COPY demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080
```

## Docker run -p

You need to specify how you wish to bind port on host with the port that the Spring application is listening on.

For example,

```sh
docker run -id -p 8080:8080 --name myapp myapp-imagename:latest
```

Comment: hi @justthink, the port 8080 is already exposed by the tomcat:jdk8-corretto base image. See https://hub.docker.com/layers/tomcat/library/tomcat/jdk8-corretto/images/sha256-e26fb82584af6b7e263ddf4e3c4cb9bce44bf4b3480f7c9cf66da427de9e77fe?context=explore

Comment: If you do not specify ` docker run -id ` (d for detach), container will exist upon detach. I recommend you to `docker ps -a` and `docker logs container-name`. Check if the container is up running and if any stacktrace is printed. I guess the Springboot application did not even start within the container.